# Boolean 2D Arrays C# Making Several Values True

Tags: c#, arrays

Hello I have just recently finished a code of a grid. The instructions allow you to go right,left,up or down and enter a specific value to move by. The problem right now however is, which value is entered is the only location that becomes true. I'm trying to get the entire amount to become true. For example fi we move right 3, it should be 3 spots = true instead of just  the last. Can anyone help me with that?

```
            // Make a bool 2d array and save already drilled values into the array
        bool[,] drill = new bool[401, 200];
        drill[200, 1] = true;
        drill[200, 2] = true;
        drill[200, 3] = true;
        drill[201, 3] = true;
        drill[202, 3] = true;
        drill[203, 3] = true;
        drill[203, 4] = true;
        drill[203, 5] = true;
        drill[204, 5] = true;
        drill[205, 5] = true;
        drill[205, 4] = true;
        drill[205, 3] = true;
        drill[206, 3] = true;
        drill[207, 3] = true;
        drill[207, 4] = true;
        drill[207, 5] = true;
        drill[207, 6] = true;
        drill[207, 7] = true;
        drill[206, 7] = true;
        drill[205, 7] = true;
        drill[204, 7] = true;
        drill[203, 7] = true;
        drill[202, 7] = true;
        drill[201, 7] = true;
        drill[200, 7] = true;
        drill[199, 7] = true;
        drill[199, 6] = true;
        drill[199, 5] = true;


        // Set some values
        bool okay = true;
        int column = -1;
        int row = -5;
        int check_column = 199;
        int check_row = 5;

        // Run a while loop
        do
        {
            // Ask the user to input a direction
            Console.WriteLine("Which direction would you like to go?");
            string direction = Console.ReadLine();

            // Ask the user to input a movement
            Console.WriteLine("What value would you like to move by?");
            string distance = Console.ReadLine();
            int new_distance = Convert.ToInt32(distance);

            // Use if statements
            if (direction == "l" || direction == "L")
            {
                column = column - new_distance;
                check_column = check_column - new_distance;

            }
            else if (direction == "u" || direction == "U")
            {
                row = row + new_distance;
                check_row = check_row - new_distance;

            }
            else if (direction == "r" || direction == "R")
            {
                column = column + new_distance;
                check_column = check_column + new_distance;
            }
            else if (direction == "d" || direction == "D")
            {
                row = row - new_distance;
                check_row = check_row + new_distance;
            }
            else if (direction == "q" || direction == "Q" || new_distance == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Program will now end.");
                okay = false;
                break;
            }

            while (new_distance > 0)
            {


                if (drill[check_column, check_row] == true && check_row >= 0 && check_row <=200 && check_column >=0 && check_column <=400 && drill[check_column, check_row] != true)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0},{1} safe", column, row);
                    break;
                }

                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0},{1} danger", column, row);
                    Console.WriteLine("Program will now end.");
                    okay = false;
                    break;

                }


            }

        } while (okay);

        if (okay == false)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Thanks for using the program!");
        }
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: A couple of things 1) `if(okay == false)` will always be true and therefore is not necessary because you are only breaking from your do while loop after setting okay = false 2) in your while loop you have competing check `drill[check_column, check_row] == true && .. && drill[check_column, check_row] != true` 3) You are never decrementing 
 `new_distance` in your while loop 4) Could you clarify what you mean _3 spots = true_. I don't see where are you setting anything to true except in your initialization

Comment: Okay for example if I am to enter "r" then "2" then it should make those 2 spots on the grid true, but right now, its only setting the EXACT value 2 right to original to true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer you question, the reason you are not seeing each move as safe is because you are not checking each position, you were simply setting your check position to the position you wanted to move and not each incremental position. I have added a class with a bit more logic in this answer because each move in your game requires slightly different logic to work.

```
public class DrillGame
{
    private const int Columns = 401;
    private const int Rows = 200;

    public void Play()
    {
        // Make a bool 2d array and save already drilled values into the array
        bool[,] drill = ProvideDrill();

        // Set some values
        bool okay = true;

        _currentGameRow = -1;
        _currentGameColumn = -5;
        _currentArrayRow = 5;
        _currentArrayColumn = 199;

        // Run a while loop
        do
        {
            // Ask the user to input a direction
            Console.WriteLine("Which direction would you like to go?");
            string direction = Console.ReadLine();

            // Ask the user to input a movement
            Console.WriteLine("What value would you like to move by?");
            string distanceInput = Console.ReadLine();
            int distanceToMove = Convert.ToInt32(distanceInput);

            // Use if statements
            if (direction == "l" || direction == "L")
            {
                okay = TryMoveLeft(distanceToMove);
            }
            else if (direction == "u" || direction == "U")
            {
                okay = TryMoveUp(distanceToMove);
            }
            else if (direction == "r" || direction == "R")
            {
                okay = TryMoveRight( distanceToMove);
            }
            else if (direction == "d" || direction == "D")
            {
                okay = TryMoveDown(distanceToMove);
            }
            else if (direction == "q" || direction == "Q" || distanceToMove == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Program will now end.");
                okay = false;
                break;
            }

        } while (okay);

        if (okay == false)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Thanks for using the program!");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private bool TryMoveLeft(int distanceToMove)
    {
        while(distanceToMove > 0)
        {
            _currentArrayColumn = _currentArrayColumn - 1;
            _currentGameColumn = _currentGameColumn - 1;

            if (!TryMoveColumn(distanceToMove))
            {
                return false;
            }

            distanceToMove--;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private bool TryMoveRight(int distanceToMove)
    {
        while (distanceToMove > 0)
        {
            _currentArrayColumn = _currentArrayColumn + 1;
            _currentGameColumn = _currentGameColumn + 1;

            if (!TryMoveColumn(distanceToMove))
            {
                return false;
            }

            distanceToMove--;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private bool TryMoveUp(int distanceToMove)
    {
        while (distanceToMove > 0)
        {
            _currentArrayRow = _currentArrayRow - 1;
            _currentGameRow = _currentGameRow - 1;

            if (!TryMoveRow(distanceToMove))
            {
                return false;
            }

            distanceToMove--;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private bool TryMoveDown(int distanceToMove)
    {
        while (distanceToMove > 0)
        {
            _currentArrayRow = _currentArrayRow + 1;
            _currentGameRow = _currentGameRow + 1;

            if (!TryMoveRow(distanceToMove))
            {
                return false;
            }

            distanceToMove--;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private bool TryMoveColumn(int distanceToMove)
    {
        var drill = ProvideDrill();

        if (_currentArrayColumn >= 0 && _currentArrayColumn < Columns && drill[_currentArrayColumn, _currentArrayRow])
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{_currentGameColumn},{_currentGameRow} safe");
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{_currentGameColumn},{_currentGameRow} danger");
            Console.WriteLine("Program will now end.");
            return false;
        }
    }

    private bool TryMoveRow(int distanceToMove)
    {
        var drill = ProvideDrill();

        if (_currentArrayRow >= 0 && _currentArrayRow < Rows && drill[_currentArrayColumn, _currentArrayRow])
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{_currentGameColumn},{_currentGameRow} safe");
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{_currentGameColumn},{_currentGameRow} danger");
            Console.WriteLine("Program will now end.");
            return false;
        }
    }

    private bool[,] ProvideDrill()
    {
        bool[,] drill = new bool[Columns, Rows];
        drill[200, 1] = true;
        drill[200, 2] = true;
        drill[200, 3] = true;
        drill[201, 3] = true;
        drill[202, 3] = true;
        drill[203, 3] = true;
        drill[203, 4] = true;
        drill[203, 5] = true;
        drill[204, 5] = true;
        drill[205, 5] = true;
        drill[205, 4] = true;
        drill[205, 3] = true;
        drill[206, 3] = true;
        drill[207, 3] = true;
        drill[207, 4] = true;
        drill[207, 5] = true;
        drill[207, 6] = true;
        drill[207, 7] = true;
        drill[206, 7] = true;
        drill[205, 7] = true;
        drill[204, 7] = true;
        drill[203, 7] = true;
        drill[202, 7] = true;
        drill[201, 7] = true;
        drill[200, 7] = true;
        drill[199, 7] = true;
        drill[199, 6] = true;
        drill[199, 5] = true;
        return drill;
    }

    private int _currentArrayRow;
    private int _currentArrayColumn;
    private int _currentGameRow;
    private int _currentGameColumn;
}
```

Sample output

[image]

Comment: So this will check every step?

Comment: @SaltyLegend. Yes this will check each step. I edited my answer because I forgot to set the okay value to the result of try move. Also, I added some sample output.

Comment: Ah thanks, but also I have to actually use the values of -1, -5. The 200, 400 values are just to set the 2d array, but for values to print they will be the -1 -+ number and -5 -+ numbers, so what will I need to change?

Comment: Your extra check_row and check_column variable make sense now. Sorry about that. Just add an extra row and column variable that you pass around the methods. I can edit my answer but it is going to take me a bit to verify the changes.

Comment: So like make a new method? If you have time, can you edit. Sorry I'm a bit lost and still understanding all of the code again lol

Comment: Take a look at my edits. I updated with what I believe you are looking for, but let me know if its not yet correct. I may have messed up the add/subtract on the directions. I also removed a bit of poor code on my part.

Comment: Sorry but for some reason the code is not working, which part goes in the main function and what goes in the class program?

Comment: What I submitted as an answer goes in its own class. You need to create an instance of the class in your Main method, assuming this is a console application. Something like `DrillGame game = new DrillGame();`

Comment: Oh so the entire code is in a class outside the main program, and I just have to call it?

Comment: Correct. The code I submitted is distinct from the Program.cs class

Comment: So if I put DrillGame game = new DrillGame(); and then Console.ReadLine(); it will run the code? Or I have to add more things

Comment: You should not need to put `Console.ReadLine` in `Program.cs` as the last line of the `Play` method has a `Console.ReadLine` that would serve the same purpose.

Comment: Strange, when I hit f5 it shows up with black screen. I may be doing something wrong however